# Connect to MySQL database from Firebird database

Tags: mysql, firebird, firebird2.5

I was wondering if it is possible to connect to a MySQL database to perform changes on a table from a firebird DB trigger? I have looked the On External command but it seems to only work for another firebird database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing built-in in Firebird to support connecting to other database systems. The `EXECUTE ... ON EXTERNAL` is only for connecting to other Firebird databases.

In Firebird 2.5 and earlier, you might be able to use UDF (User-Defined Function) to do this. However, you would need to develop this yourself.

In Firebird 3, you could also use a UDR (User-Defined Routine) to do this, but you would need to develop this UDR yourself. You can do this in Java using [fbjava](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/fbjava) (warning: alpha version, and not under active development), in C# using [FbNetExternalEngine](https://www.tabsoverspaces.com/tools/fb-net-external-engine) (note: commercial product), but you can also develop in C, C++, Pascal and other languages that support native bindings. Unfortunately the API for that is poorly documented.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will explore UDF to see if that can work for me

Comment: I am somewhat fond of UDF but would not suggest to use there. UDF's are designed for small and fast (and thus, pure) functions. Like calculating sine/cosine, for example. Abusing it to lock server engine's thread make slllooowww conneciton to another RDBMS, make complex query, pack it into some JSON or XML and return as text blob, then inside Firebird by some other mean to parse that all - it would be bad abuse. One better take C IDE and try to develope Y-valve module like Fyracle did :-D

Comment: @CarlosPayan, any success with the UDF to connect MySQL with Firebird? .. I am trying something similar to with MSSQL.. If you post some guidance will be helpful. Thanks.